# Prince of Persia: Based on Movie or Game

Tags: prince-of-persia

When I watched Prince of Persia, it really seemed I was playing a video game. The Game was released before the movie was.

The question was: Was the movie based off the video game, or was video game just out before the movie. Making the the game based on the movie.

Comment: Related: [Is the story of the Prince of Persia movie purely based on the titular video game?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/9915/49)